# TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list

Tags: python, pymongo

I am running into error at line `collection.find({}).sort({"_id":-1})`,how do I sort a collection of documents in mongodb?

```
count = 1
cursor = collection.find({}).sort({"_id":-1})
for document in cursor:
    if count !=100:
        logger.info('COUNT %s'%count)
        logger.info('document %s'%document)
    else:
        logger.info('Exiting...')
        sys.exit(0)
```

Error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ibait_data_integrity.py", line 79, in <module>
    main()
  File "ibait_data_integrity.py", line 66, in main
    cursor = collection.find({}).sort({"_id":-1})
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 703, in sort
    keys = helpers._index_list(key_or_list, direction)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 52, in _index_list
    raise TypeError("if no direction is specified, "
TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list
```

Comment: try with just "collection.find().sort("_id":-1)". Remove "{}" brackets. refer here https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mongodb_sort.asp

Answer (score 29):

try with just:

```
collection.find().sort("_id", -1)
```

Answer (score 13):

`collection.find().sort("_id",-1)` should do it - without the '{}'.
you can also try :
`collection.find().sort("_id", pymongo.ASCENDING)` when using python

Comment: This is not correct.

sort accepts field name and a direction, either ASCENDING or DESCENDING.

Above your ":" should be replaced with a ","

resulting in `collection.find().sort("_id", -1)` or `collection.find().sort("_id", pymongo.ASCENDING)`

Answer (score 0):

The `.sort()` function for PyMongo has mentioned syntax - `(self:cursor, key_or_list, direction)`.

The PyMongo provides direction variables pymongo.ASCENDING and pymongo.DESCENDING. Separating the `.find()` and `.sort()` functions worked for me.

With similar database settings like you - I tried this code block

```
degree_collection = db["degrees"]
degrees = degree_collection.find({}, {"degree_id": 1, "degree": 1, "_id": 0})
degrees = degrees.sort("degree_id", pymongo.ASCENDING)
```

Which is working for me.

PS: The integrated version of this code, i.e. using find().sort() format with the same attributes isn't working for me.