# pymongo key_or_list must be an instance of list

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

could somebody please help me and tell me how i can fix this pymongo error?

```py
  cluster = pymongo.MongoClient("xxx")
  db = cluster['Coins']
  ada_db = db['ada']
  eos_db = db['eos']
  miota_db = db['miota']
  nano_db = db['nano']
  xrp_db = db['xrp']
  xmr_db = db["xmr"]

  BTC = getPrice("BTC")
  ETH = getPrice("ETH")
  XRP = getPrice("XRP")
  EOS = getPrice("EOS")
  ADA = getPrice("ADA")
  IOTA =getPrice("IOTA")
  NANO =getPrice("NANO")
  XMR = getPrice("XMR")

  ada_db.insertOne({'_id': (ada_db.find({}).sort({"_id":-1}).limit(1) + 1), 'value': ADA})
  eos_db.insertOne({'_id': (eos_db.find({}).sort({"_id":-1}).limit(1) + 1), 'value': EOS})
  miota_db.insertOne({'_id': (miota_db.find({}).sort({"_id":-1}).limit(1) + 1), 'value': IOTA})
  nano_db.insertOne({'_id': (nano_db.find({}).sort({"_id":-1}).limit(1) + 1), 'value': NANO})
  xrp_db.insertOne({'_id': (xrp_db.find({}).sort({"_id":-1}).limit(1) + 1), 'value': XRP})
  xmr_db.insertOne({'_id': (xmr_db.find({}).sort({"_id": -1}).limit(1) + 1), 'value': XMR})
```

```
TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list
```

would be cool if you can help me :smile:

```py
ada_db.insertOne({'_id': (ada_db.find({}).sort({"_id":-1}).limit(1) + 1), 'value': ADA})
```

this is where pycharm marks the error

````
    ada_db.insertOne({'_id': (ada_db.find({}).sort({"_id":-1}).limit(1) + 1), 'value': ADA})
  File "C:\Users\brend\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 762, in sort
    keys = helpers._index_list(key_or_list, direction)
  File "C:\Users\brend\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\helpers.py", line 74, in _index_list
    raise TypeError("if no direction is specified, "
TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: if no direction is specified, key\_or\_list must be an instance of list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57778658/typeerror-if-no-direction-is-specified-key-or-list-must-be-an-instance-of-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As taken from the answer in [TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57778658/typeerror-if-no-direction-is-specified-key-or-list-must-be-an-instance-of-list)

Remove the `{}` in `.find()` and use 2 parameters instead of a dictionary in `.sort()`

```py
ada_db.insertOne({'_id': (ada_db.find().sort("_id", -1).limit(1) + 1), 'value': ADA})
```